# When it is compulsory to perform 7 and 35 pass Erase?

Tags: security, hardware, erase

I am working on a module in which on the hard disk both 7 and 35 pass algorithm is used. it is enclosed in an if(1) loop which will perform the 7 and 35 pass erase. is it specific to any hardware or something?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.
Azeem

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I consider hdd data erased after one pass with random data of any quality. Multiple passes stem from ancient hardware, magnetizing large patches of disc surface where you could recreate previous data. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) has some sources on this.

Only use 7 or 35 passes when you are legally bound to do so. For this, ask your local lawyer.

Plus, when in a hurry, use a punch tool and a hammer.